# Converting buffer to unsigned int and using bitmask

Tags: java, objective-c, byte, nsdata

I have 4 bytes of data (stored as an unsigned int) which I would like to use.

When this is 1 byte of data, this has been solved using:

```
//Java 

buffer.get() & 0xFF

//Objective-C

uint32_t buffer;
[data getBytes:&buffer range:NSMakeRange(2, 1)];
uint32_t payloadLength = buffer & 0xFFu;
//data = d1021b53
//buffer = 897307; payloadLength: 27
```

In Java, **for 4 bytes**, this has been done using:

```
//Java

buffer.getInt() & 0xFFFFFFFFL

//Current not working Objective-C code
uint32_t buffer;
[data getBytes:&buffer range:NSMakeRange(2, 4)];
uint32_t payloadLength = CFSwapInt32BigToHost(buffer);
//data: 0103940f b7626361
//buffer = 1656164244; payloadLength: 2484057954 (should be = ~80)
```

For Objective-C / C, I'm having difficulty working with the 4 bytes and bitmasks.

Anyone have any help with this?

Answer (score 1):

To convert your 4 bytes to an integer you can do something similar as your 1 byte code, but you must deal with the endian order - that is you need to know which way around the 4 bytes are stored, low or high byte first.

So start with a 4-byte buffer:

```
uint32_t buffer; // or use int32_t if signed
```

Copy the bytes:

```
[data getBytes:&buffer range:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];
```

And convert the order of the bytes to the host order. If the data is big endian do:

```
uint32_t payloadLength = CFSwapInt32BigToHost(buffer);
```

or if its little endian:

```
uint32_t payloadLength = CFSwapInt32LittleToHost(buffer);
```

and you are done.

Comment: I have had no joy using this. I have changed the original to reflect changing the objective-c 1 byte example to use an unsigned int (as it should have). 

When I try use CFSwapInt32BigToHost (or Little) with the 4 byte value, the result is unintelligible. Even using that on the 1 byte example above does not work. 

Any other suggestions on how to replicate the java 0xFFFFFFFF bitmask?

Comment: There is no need to use a bit mask in this case. Can you edit your question (as putting code in a comment doesn't really work), show the code you now have based on this answer, and include the results of `NSLog(@"%@\n%8x\n%8x", data, buffer, payloadLength)`? (cut out some of the dump of `data` if it is long!)

Comment: I have edited the post to show example values, and to show what it is now, which is not working.

Comment: Your edited code is only getting 1 byte (`NSMakeRange(dataOffset, 1)`), it needs to get 4 as shown above.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! That was just in the post, the code was still getting 4 bytes.

Comment: You will need to add the results of the `NSLog` as suggested above for anyone to get any further – you might say you expect ~80 but without seeing the input data it is just conjecture that is what you have.

Comment: Thanks for your patience! Ok, I've added the data. NB: I have also added the position of the data in the range.

Comment: Also, I do not know exactly if it will be 80, as I am just reading it (I just have an expected value based on its context).

Comment: Your byte data is: `01, 03, 94, 0f,  b7, 62, 63, 61`. You are starting at offset 2 so you have 0x940fb762 (2484057954) big-endian and 0x62b70f94 (1656164244) little endian. So the new code is working correctly, you just don't have the bytes you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check! I will update this when I resolve my issue anyway